# StatusCallback using Messaging Api

Tags: php, twilio

I've scoured the web searching for the proper way to add the statuscallback url with the messaging api in php.

```
 $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage($from, $to, $body);
```

I've tried using an keyed array after the `$body` variable, tried sending an image after the `$body` variable then using just a link and a keyed array with no success.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it should just be a numeric array based on [line 37](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/a876df2cd5bc873beb450a56e6e410680a5b4e4c/Services/Twilio/Rest/Messages.php#L37)

Comment: That's actually for media urls if you are sending mms messages... Found the answer though.  See below.

Comment: Nice, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I scoped around the Services_Twilio_Rest_Messages class and added an extra `null` input after the message body with the keyed array like so:

```
 $client->account->messages->sendMessage($from, $to, $body, null, array('StatusCallback' => '{callback url}'));
```